# How to upload an image of a map on ROS using OpenCV?

Tags: opencv, ros, dijkstra

I need to apply Dijkstra's algorithm using ROS and Opencv.
I have been given a png file and I need to convert it into an occupancy grid.

[Map](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BAGgU.jpg)

I've tried searching online but didn't find anything that fits my case.

(Also, if anyone knows any good beginner tutorials on ROS then I would be very grateful)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you have the pic file (usually in png format), you create the yaml file 
which may look like

```
image: map.png
resolution: 0.1
origin: [0.0, 0.0, 0.0]
occupied_thresh: 0.65
free_thresh: 0.196
negate: 0
```

You can read the details [here](http://wiki.ros.org/map_server)

Then start `roscore` and try

```
rosrun map_server map_server mymap.yaml
```

Be careful with the paths (use the same folder for both)